# Не работает корзина (EasyNetShop) в Google Sites

Tags: html, css, корзина

Не работает кнопка "Купить" с сайта EasyNetShop. Я создаю сайт одежды в Google Sites. Корзина добавляется, а кнопка нет.

Что делать и как исправить?

Вот код кнопки:

```
<a class="btn-ens-action btn-ens-style" data-rel="6ff67af3157125">Купить</a>
```

Comment: код не добавили

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка "купить" и корзина находятся в разных iframe. События между фреймами не передаются. Если кнопку добавления товара разместить в том же фрейме, что и сама корзина - добавление будет работать. Выходом из ситуации является подключение корзины через GoogleTagManager.

Ответы на любые вопросы можно также получить в разделе "поддержка" (в личном кабинете сервиса EasyNetShop.ru)